# Angular - Generate HTML file with JS and send to server

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular-http

My goal is to generate an html file in javascript (based on form inputs), and use Angular's $http to send this generated file to the server (php) for storage. Is this possible?

So far I've tried generating HTML strings on the client side and send the string over, and use php's file_put_contents() to generate the html file. But I would like to generate the html file on the client side. As the html gets more complex, I don't want to be sending long and complex strings.

**Javascript (inside the controller)**

```
$http({
    url: "/test.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {"content":"<h1>hello world</h1>"}
});
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
    $input = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($input);
    file_put_contents("index.html", $data->content);
?>
```

I prefer to generate the html file on the client side because I want to reduce server load.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Saving HTML files is probably not what you should be doing. You should generally save only the unique data and use some kind of HTML templating to generate HTML only when it is needed.

Comment: Any recommendations for a php based HTML templating engine?

Comment: since your using angular, I would use angular's built in templating http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates

Comment: You might want to use some template generting library like inbuilt Anguar templating or something like Handlebars

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twig for PHP templating. Or PHP Plates - http://platesphp.com/

Read the POSTed data from PHP and generate using the template.

Pseudo codes:

```
<?php
    $input = $_POST['content'];
    $html = generateTemplate($input);
    file_put_contents($fileName, $html);
?>
```